# Parse: Any "backend" actually needed?

Tags: parse-platform

I am reading up about Parse. It seems like to me that the main benefit is removing the need for a backend. However, I am starting to wonder if this is a good thing.

Assume I need an iOS and Android app. I imagine they both start developing models in the frontend. But isit this a problem if they both store data differently? Or maybe validate/process differently? Lets say there is a document to sync such decisions. Isn't it more work that each platform will do the same thing again?

Lets say to rectify this, I start developing APIs in cloud code for this. Am I not back to square one? It becomes similar to just building APIs with the usual tools like Express/Rails?

Maybe I am understanding it wrong?

Comment: The unusual premise of the question is that the different clients would have different data models, validation or processing.  They wouldn't.

Comment: @danh, I am not sure I understand. I dont mean different clients (talking platform here. eg. Android vs iOS) will have different "models" etc. But they will need to implement the same thing over and over in both platforms. So I felt that this seemed like a bad idea. If one platform goes out of sync, it might break the other. To solve this, I might create an API that apps will talk to, but I felt this will bring me back to square one (little benefit from working in say NodeJS or Rails)

Comment: I think I see your point, but what you're getting with parse is a shared, remote model and some tools to administer it.  To put it in MVC terms, when you decided to develop for more than one platform, you sort of decided to repeat VC work in two different code bases.  Your multi-platform parse app needs to repeat some controller code to call the shared backend, but you're still saved the much of the dev work on the server

Comment: @danh, means the main benefit of Parse is to remove the need for server correct? As in no need to write API's just perhaps some hooks when objects are created. And perhaps some cloud functions and background jobs. If I start using Express on Parse, that kind of defeats the purpose of using Parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse removes the need for a specifically hosted back end in a lot of cases. That doesn't mean you shouldn't use cloud code to provide standard processing capability, security, privacy, etc for your platform. Parse also can't handle everything (like systems that store a lot of binary data). You need to consider what your system is and how you want it to operate. Putting common logic on a server and minimising the work done by clients of the system is a good plan, parse can help with that in a lot of cases. It also helps by offering other add-ons like push notification, email distribution, social login handling...